# When creating an instance of the class itself in the main method, does the object get deleted right after the main method ends?

Tags: java, object

```
public class Test {
int x = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player a = new Test();
        a.foo();
    }
public void foo() {System.out.print(x);}
}
```

When I run this code, it prints x. Isn't the instance of the class supposed to be deleted when the main method ends? Why isn't it deleted? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know you can't force it, but you can give it a hint/suggestion that it should run. Whether it listens to you or not is on it's own discretion.

Comment: right, not a very pedantic poor choice of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't the instance of the class supposed to be deleted when the main method ends? Why isn't it deleted?

At the point `x` is printed, the `main` method hasn't finished executing.

Once the method actually does finish, provided there are no other references to the object, it is garbage collected either immediately, later, or never. That's the only guarantee you get from GC.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that, once the program ends, the class `main` runs in is effectively gone.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't realise that it's still running when the method is called! Thanks!